# Asp.Net core ActionFilter context request body disposed

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a asp.net core web api project in which I created an action filter to log  every call made to the api

```
public class RequestLoggerActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RequestLoggerActionFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("RequestLogger");
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        request.Body.Position = 0;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            var bodyString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            _logger.LogInformation($"API call recevied on {request.Method.ToUpper()} {request.Path} RequestBody: {bodyString}");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

This piece of code works ok in most case. I get problem when my controller method return a 201 code using `CreatedAtAction` method

```
return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { Id= myObject.Id });
```

the problem is, when I hit my controller method which creates an object, it enters a first time in my actionfilter and logs the request correctly. Then, when the return line is reached , it hits my actionfilter a second time (I'm not sure why a second request is send, I guess it's kind of doing the same thing as a Redirect). The second time `OnActionExecuting` of my actionFilter is executed, this line of code throws an exception

```
request.Body.Position = 0;
```

> 'Cannot access a disposed object.'

Body of my request is disposed. My ActionFilter is registered this way in `Startup.cs` file

```
services.AddMvc(c =>
                {
                    c.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestLoggerActionFilter));
                }
            );
```

The lifecycle of my actionFilter is Scoped, I also tried Transient, but it doesn't fix the problem.

```
services.AddScoped<RequestLoggerActionFilter>();
```

Comment: I'm confused. One request will call OnActionExecuting and then OnActionExecuted. That's the normal flow. Your write about OnActionExecuted but your code shows only OnActionExecuting…

Comment: In addition to that the line `request.Body.Position = 0;` always throws *NotSupportedException* according to my tests (ASP.NET Core 2.0 & 2.1)

Comment: What is your .net core version?

Comment: @AdamSimon I use .net core 2.1 and can confirm that this line of code is working fine

Comment: @ChristophLütjen The purpose of this actionfilter is to log every request. I do it on OnActionExecuting, I have nothing other to do on OnActionExecuted. An actionFilter is not mandatory to implement every event of the mvc workflow

Comment: @ChristophLütjen my bad, code didn't reflect what was written in explanation, corrected !

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with `request.EnableRewind();` and code below, it works with `CreatedAtAction`.

```
    public class RequestLoggerActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RequestLoggerActionFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("RequestLogger");
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        request.EnableRewind();
        request.Body.Position = 0;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            var bodyString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            _logger.LogInformation($"API call recevied on {request.Method.ToUpper()} {request.Path} RequestBody: {bodyString}");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still got the same problem. Can you show me how you registered the actionFilter in startup class and how it's registered on serviceprovider. Plus can you confirm that this piece of code is hit twice, once when the controller's action method is reached, and a second time when method CreatedAtAction called ?

Comment: @NicolasBoisvert Here is my [test project](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/e9c32eb4ea594df3b1a640765d8c3b091474bcbb/MVCPro). Could you share us a reproduceable project through github?